# Signals do not seem to work, honestly tried a lot

Tags: django

creating a user model auth for website,  used signals to auto create but seems to not get triggered, confused
user is created, but not profile
can someone help me this time

models.py

```
class InterestChoice(models.Model):
    INTEREST_CHOICES = (
        ('A', 'traveling'),
        ('B', 'exercise'),
    )
    interest = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=INTEREST_CHOICES, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_interest_display()


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    dob = models.DateField()
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, null=True)
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(InterestChoice)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user.username} Profile"

    def save(self):
        super().save()
```

signals.py

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user = instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

here's the apps.py code
apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class UsersConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'users'

    def ready(self):
        import users.signals
```

Comment: You may need to restart your django server for this to take effect, the django signals are loaded on startup

Comment: Also as a side note: 
    def save(self):
        super().save() is not needed.

Comment: How is your AppConfig itself imported? Are you referencing it in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yes

Comment: changed users to 'users.apps.UsersConfig' and it worked, thanks